# How to get cosmosDB or storageAccount connection in DebugActivityLogger of botframework C#

Tags: botframework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-account

I want to save my conversation history to Azure Cosmos DB or storageAccount.

1. About Azure Cosmos DB

It seems really easy to use [IActivityLogger](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-Middleware/DebugActivityLogger.cs). But I don't know how could I get the DB connection which is connected in Global.asax.cs. Or it's better to get it again in IActivityLogger?

2. About storageAccount

According [this](https://chatbotslife.com/managing-state-and-logging-chat-history-in-microsoft-bot-framework-aeb330c688c5), SDK also provides a way to save conversation history using storageAccount. But the Activity has been compressed. I want to save my real conversation[JSON] which is not compressed, to storageAccount.

I'm trying to insert a row to Azure table storage which has compressed data.
But Activity0 is always null.

```
public class ActivityEntity : TableEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Empty constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public ActivityEntity()
        { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct from an IActivity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="activity"></param>
        public ActivityEntity(byte[] Activity)
        {
            PartitionKey = "111";
            RowKey = "11";
            From = "111";
            Recipient = "111";
            Activity0 = Activity;
            Version = 3.0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Version number for the underlying activity.
        /// </summary>
        public double Version { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Channel identifier for sender.
        /// </summary>
        public string From { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Channel identifier for receiver.
        /// </summary>
        public string Recipient { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Logged activity.
        /// </summary>
        [IgnoreProperty]
        public byte[] Activity0 { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a partition key given <paramref name="channelId"/> and <paramref name="conversationId"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelId">Channel where activity happened.</param>
        /// <param name="conversationId">Conversation where activity happened.</param>
        /// <returns>Partition key.</returns>
        public static string GeneratePartitionKey(string channelId, string conversationId)
        {
            return $"{channelId}|{conversationId}";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate row key for ascending <paramref name="timestamp"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timestamp">Timestamp of activity.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GenerateRowKey(DateTime timestamp)
        {
            return $"{timestamp.Ticks:D19}";
        }

    }




     class Program
    {
        public static object CloudConfigurationManager { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagetesthuafu;AccountKey=iQ0EZexm3wbpWZqly2HtVH0/CZKRyMY9l2b0g20AQkUz7BX0BFLuBinMyYLe8Ow/zOA7vJqAMSxSHllT3JTL2g==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "TemperatureData" table.
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("messagelog");



            TableQuery<BotDataRow> query = new TableQuery<BotDataRow>();
            var data = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
            var dataarry = data.ToArray();


            var aa = dataarry.First();
            var activity = aa.Activity0;
            var after = Decompress(activity);


            CloudTable tableTEST = tableClient.GetTableReference("messagelog");


            byte[] bb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(after);
            ActivityEntity customer4 = new ActivityEntity(bb);

            // Create the InsertOrReplace TableOperation.
            TableOperation insertOrReplaceOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(customer4);

            // added to the table.
            table.Execute(insertOrReplaceOperation);
        }
```

Comment: `I don't know how could I get the DB connection which is connected in Global.asax.cs. Or it's better to get it again in IActivityLogger?` Do you want to intercept all messages within your ActivityLogger, and then use [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB Client Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started#SetupVS) to create JSON documents for activities and store them in your Cosmos DB collection?

Comment: `But the Activity has been compressed. I want to save my real conversation[JSON] which is not compressed, to storageAccount.` You can find [the source code of **TableLogger** in github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs#L429), as you said, activity would be compressed, if you'd like to save real conversation[JSON] in Azure table storage, you could implement by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't know how to real conversation[JSON] in Azure table storage.
I'm trying to insert a row to Azure table storage which has compressed data.
But Activity0 is always null.

Comment: I have upload my code. can you help why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an **IActivityLogger** implementation that uses **DocumentDb** doesn't require much code.  Here's an example using the **Azure Cosmos DB Emulator**:

```
class DocumentDbActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    const string DbKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
    const string DbUri = "https://localhost:8081";
    const string DbId = "ActivityLogsDb";
    const string CollectionId = "ActivityLogsColleciton";

    async Task IActivityLogger.LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = activity.AsMessageActivity();
            if (message != null)
            {
                using (var documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(DbUri), DbKey))
                {
                    await documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DbId, CollectionId), message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, register it in Global.asax.cs:

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
{
     builder.RegisterType<DocumentDbActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time to use this kind of DB. If it is oracle, usually i need to close it after using it. How about cosmos DB? Are there anything I should pay attention to while using it?

Comment: This is an oddity and annoyance: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/219

Comment: Thank you so much... I'm testing how to insert a Json data to Azure table storage like Activity0.. Can you give me some suggestions? By the way it's not necessary to do it in the bot